# Firefox web extension change url of new tab addon

Tags: json, google-chrome, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have built a web extension addon for Firefox and Chrome. In Chrome, the address bar is empty, which is why I want Firefox too.

If I click on "new tab", the following URL is set on the address bar: `moz-extension://5a4137a2-ede8-4f1d-838c-20069831ab38/index.html`. Can I change this to something else? An empty address bar would be great.

This is my manifest.json

```
...
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372996) that did not clear the address bar, but it's fixed as of Firefox 57.

You can customize the tab title by setting the [`<title>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) element in your new tab page's HTML. From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_url_overrides) for the extension manifest.json file:

> It's very good practice to include a  for the page, or the tab's title will be the "moz-extension://..." URL.